# Куда захостить приложение на php?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, хостинг

Есть приложение, работающее на PHP.

В целом - как сайт, но некоторые файлы работают по 7-10 часов без остановки.

Стандартный хостинг не дает столько работать. Куда можно выложить, чтобы могла спокойно без ошибок работать такое долгое время?

UPD. С Линуксом не дружу, с его консолью тем более. Не хотелось бы учить линукс-сервера вместо того, чтобы докручивать приложение, прошу линуксоидов строго не пинать.

Comment: Есть Windows сервер, но с его настройкой и изучением времени потратите больше, чем выльете сайт на хостинг с UNIX системой, когда UNIX стоят почти на 90% всех серверов.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вам в выборе поможет https://hosters.ru/

Но лично я бы всё таки взял дешевенький vps и развернул бы там требуемое.

Comment: А на VPS оно с интерфейсом будет? А то опыт с консолью исключительно неудачный(

Comment: Если у вас есть время на эксперименты - советую изучить. В линуксах основная работа делается об консоль. Более того, советую изучить сразу ansible - это позволит вам легко деплоить свои проекты.

Comment: У некоторых VPS-провайдеров есть возможность докупить панель управления, например, ISPmanager или DirectAdmin.